# Private Function rewrite in magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides

i want to override helper class method

private function `_getGeneralFromAttributeSets`(array $attributeSetIds)
i use this code and create helper in my module folder

```
<preference for="Test\Test\Helper\Magento\Attribute" type="Abc\Def\Helper\Magento\Attribute" />
```

---

```
class Attribute extends \Test\TestHelper\Magento\Attribute
{

    private function _getGeneralFromAttributeSets(array $attributeSetIds)
    {}
```

but not working i dont know my be the fucntion is private is that issue

Comment: how i change my logic

Comment: Overriding private method of class is totally discouraged.